# HTMLAgilityPack get InnerText but keep <a> elements

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My original text is something like this:

```
<p>
Lorem <span><i></i>ipsum<span> <a href="">dolor</a> sit <a href="link.html">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing <span>elit</span>.
</p>
```

I am trying to keep only text + A elements, so the output should be something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum <a href="">dolor</a> sit <a href="link.html">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Both

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerText;
```

and

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerHtml;
```

are not working for this case. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved that with regex, I hope it will help someone in the future:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Don't forget to add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```